# Convert ppt file to pptx in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, powerpoint

### **Is there any way to convert .ppt files to .pptx files.**

**Objective:** I need to extract text from table (with Column Names as Name, address, contact number, email, etc) from .ppt files. For this I followed this approach:

*I converted .ppt file to pdf and then extracted the data from pdf using PDFminer. The text extracted from pdf is not separated by any delimiter. Due to this it is very difficult to  distinguish names and other fields in the table.*

Probable solution I am working on:

1. Convert .ppt files to .pptx
2. Parse xml of .pptx file to get the formatted text

I am stuck at first step of converting the file format from .ppt to .pptx. 
I couldn't find any solution for converting .ppt file format to .pptx formt in python.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to convert ppt into pptx using Python?  As far as I remember, you could easily do this using Powerpoint 2010.

Comment: I need to extract text from ppt files. And I have thousands of ppt files. Powerpoint 2010 allows bulk file conversion?

Comment: Ok, your point is valid( you could add this is the question description). Let me try the code.

Comment: Post the entire trace, it seems like you're missing a package, and that can be fixed regardless of file type.

Comment: What operating system are you running on? There are options in Windows that are not available on other OSes.

Comment: I am using windows 7 operating system. If there is any solution on Linux or Mac please suggest, I will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have created this code hope this works for you :

```
    import win32com.client
    PptApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
    PptApp.Visible = True
    PPtPresentation = PptApp.Presentations.Open(r'D:\ppt\sample.ppt')
    PPtPresentation.SaveAs(r'D:\ppt\final.pptx', 24)
    PPtPresentation.close()
    PptApp.Quit()
```

Comment: Although useful, this sadly does not work in Python 3.

Comment: Any new way for python3?

Comment: pptx -> 24. Share list of PowerPoint extension code document

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS Homebrew users: install Apache Tika (`brew install tika`)

The command-line interface works like this:

```
tika --text something.ppt > something.txt
```

And to use it inside python script:

```
import os
os.system("tika --text temp.ppt > temp.txt")
```

You will be able to do it and that is the only solution I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pptx *.ppt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Work perfect on anaconda 3 + jupyter notebook

```
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import win32com.client

paths = glob('C:\\yourfilePath\\*.ppt', recursive=True)

def save_as_pptx(path):
    PptApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
    PptApp.Visible = True
    PPtPresentation = PptApp.Presentations.Open(path)
    PPtPresentation.SaveAs(path+'x', 24)
    PPtPresentation.close()
    PptApp.Quit()
    
for path in paths:
    print(path.replace("\\yourfile\\", "\\yourfile_pptx\\"))
    save_as_pptx(path)
```